# why am i getting error accepting android license?

Tags: flutter

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class home.Documents..dependencies.android-sdk.cmdline-tools.latest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: home/Documents//dependencies/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest
```

and it's there! I've checked it, the folder exists

Answer (score -1):

Have enabled command-line tools?

You do this by going into android studio and going to More Actions/SDK Manger/SDK Tools and select command-line tools then click install.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah, i had already done that beforehand. But the weird thing is that my folder name is ".dependencies" but it shows "//dependencies" in the error. I did not think of it much, because i basically "pwd" in the folder and pasted it in flutter config but maybe something like that is causing error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).